# No Advertisers Found When Using MCNearbyServiceBrowser

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I have a MultipeerService class which is used to start advertising and browsing sessions. For some reason I am not sure why I am not able to see any advertisers.

**MultipeerService.m**

```
-(void) startAdvertising
{
    NSString *name = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];

    MCPeerID *peerId = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:name];
    self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerId];
    self.session.delegate = self;

    self.advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:peerId discoveryInfo:nil serviceType:kServiceType];
    self.advertiser.delegate = self;

    [self.advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
}

-(void) startBrowsing
{
    NSString *name = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];

    MCPeerID *peerId = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:name];
    self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerId];
    self.session.delegate = self;

    self.browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:peerId serviceType:kServiceType];
    self.browser.delegate = self;

    [self.browser startBrowsingForPeers];
}
```

I start the advertiser like the following:

```
 _multipeerConnectivityService = [[MultipeerConnectivityService alloc] init];
[_multipeerConnectivityService startAdvertising];
```

I create a new instance of multipeerConnectivityService for browsing and invoke the startBrowsing method.

When I check in the foundPeer method in the multipeerConnectivityService I see nothing invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of your kServiceType??

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `browser:didNotStartBrowsingForPeers:` delegate method. If it is invoked, the `NSError` object you receive will help you diagnose the problem.

```
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser didNotStartBrowsingForPeers:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog( @"Unable to start browsing for peers. Error: %@", error );
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and the method is implemented but this also doesn get called..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure everything is a property. Even the custom classes that you made for encapsulating the multipeer connectivity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the same session to both advertiser and browser. Session should be global and should be running for as long as possible.